# Initialize C-style array with non-constant variables or function's return value

Tags: c++, c++11, c++98

Is the below code a valid, portable and fashionable code in C++ 11?

```
uintptr_t sysIDs[] =
{
  obj1->GetSysObj(),
  obj2->GetSysObj(),
  obj3->GetSysObj()
};
```

I mean it compiles in my compiler and from what I googled, it is okay. I just want to be sure because I have not found this exact example anywhere.

Also, will it work in C++98 and in C?

Comment: Yes, that looks ok (if `GetSysObj()` does  `return reinterpret_cast<uintptr_t>(...);`) - but why not have real object pointers? It will not work in C because C doesn't have classes. C++98 didn't have `uintptr_t`.

Comment: In cross platform app it hides the OS specific handles(pointers) in the implementation files. What if we don't use classes and uintptr_t in the example code?

Comment: Perhaps you should take a look at [pimpl](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/pimpl) then.